# Problem compilation project spring "Cannot execute request on any known server"

Tags: java, spring, compilation, spring-tool-suite

I created a spring project thanks to "https://start.spring.io/".

I have not changed anything in the project and I just want to launch it, but the problem is that from the moment

or I run the program does not stop to compile and put me this error message from time to time, but continues to turn.

```
2018-09-26 09:55:59.113  WARN 72 --- [nfoReplicator-0] c.n.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator     : There was a problem with the instance info replicator
com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:112) ~[eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56) ~[eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$1.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:59) ~[eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77) ~[eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56) ~[eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.register(DiscoveryClient.java:829) ~[eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
at com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator.run(InstanceInfoReplicator.java:121) ~[eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_131]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_131]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_131]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_131]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_131]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_131]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_131]
```

Comment: Please post your pom.xml or gradle + your spring boot starter class.Apparently your app is compiling fine but cant locate the Eureka discovery server.

Comment: What version of Spring Boot and what version of Spring Cloud? Apparently there is some problem with your version compatibility

Comment: It's ok, i have post my answer. Sorry for the photos because the code tab doesnt not work

Comment: Not your STS version, your Spring cloud version. Alsoyou need to learn Spring Cloud : https://www.udemy.com/microservices-with-spring-cloud/learn/v4/overview

Comment: @HKX As stated in the "How to format" section, you can indent code by typing 4 spaces, not by the tab character

Comment: @georgesvan Thank you for your answer but I do not understand, you mean that my spring cloud is not the right version? Especially I create it on spring.io ...